# Error: This site is currently unavailable. And unable to login to CP

Tags: error, login, super-admin, admin.php

I'm running into a strange problem. A couple of days ago, my client started noticing that the site has an error:

```
Error Message
This site is currently unavailable
```

And the CP (admin.php) gives me this error:

```
Error
You are not authorized to perform this action
```

So it is impossible to login to the CP

**No luck trying these solutions out:**

- Database settings seems to be right
- DB Connection is fine
- System is ON
- Tried from different device and different IP Address
- Can't find any strange things in my log files
- In my config debug is on. No other errors
- Tried removing my .htaccess
- Cleared my browser cache
- Cleared system/cache folder
- Centos 6.5 is up to date
- Plesk is up to date
- EE is up to date 2.8.1

If you want access or want to see my config file just PM.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the domain still points at the correct site? It hasn't been repointed to an older version perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "This site is currently unavailable" error suggests to me the IP addresses or usernames or something has been added to the "banned" list. This is how you check and fix this.

**--------->>>>>>>> BEFORE YOU PROCEED... BACK UP YOUR DATABASE**

**--------->>>>>>>> THEN BACK THE DATABASE UP AGAIN**

=============================

1. Go into the exp_sites table in the database
2. Copy the serialized content from site_system_preferences onto your clipboard
3. Go to [**Online PHP Unserializer**](http://blog.tanist.co.uk/files/unserialize/index.php)
4. Paste the contents of your clipboard into the "Unserializer input" field on the left
5. Check the "base64 decode (top level)" box that is at the bottom right of that field
6. Click "Unserialize" button
7. Scroll down to see the "Re-serializer input" fields.
8. Check the contents of these items:

   - [banned_ips] =>
   - [banned_emails] =>
   - [banned_usernames] =>
   - [banned_screen_names] =>
9. Remove anything in the right column of those 4 fields
10. Click "Re-serialize" button
11. Copy the contents of the "Re-serializer output" field to your clipboard
12. Go into the exp_sites table in the database
13. Remove the contents of site_system_preferences and paste the serialized content from your clipboard
14. Save the data

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the site has been compromised? Do you have access to the site's SuperUser login?

I would be tweaking the database with PHPMyAdmin. Try resetting the SuperUser member, or try tinkering with the system's settings in the DB.

Most likely the 'guest' member group is now 'now allowed to see the site when it is offline', and all other groups are unable to access the control panel?

Comment: yes all access to the CP is impossible. Even superAdmin. and the site is online.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see in the DB, table exp_members, if everything is OK, your email address and username for example. It could give you an idea if someone has messed your DB and your login info.

Answer (score 0):

Haha my client banned al the IP numbers except his own. He did not know how to make the site offline.

So problem solved!